# How to order AOP aspect and MVC interceptor?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have a controller method which is annotated with 2 custom annotations.

One of them is processed with `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` which is a part of Spring MVC. 
The other is processed by AOP `@Aspect`.

It appears that the first one always takes precedence over the last.

Putting `@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` does not work for this case.

Is there any way to arrange the execution order between these two?

Answer (score 2):

There is an interceptor in Spring `ExposeInvocationInterceptor` with `@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1)`, & javadoc says

> If used, this interceptor will normally be the first in the interceptor chain.

So, there can't be any interceptor with higher order than this. So, if you add `+1`, i.e. the same precedence as `ExposeInvocationInterceptor`(or higher), it will work.

So, I have tried following & it works:

`@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1)`

`@Order(value = Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1)`

as apparently `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE = Integer.MIN_VALUE`.